Skipping any unreachable network device using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor in python
With my portion of the code below using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor
if __name__ == "__main__":
    xw.Book("Main_Template.xlsm").set_mock_caller()
    test1 = CombineCodes()

    try:
        with open("output.txt", 'w') as writefile:
            with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                results = executor.map(test1.code, test1.v_hostname_ip)

                for result in results:
                    writefile.write(result)
    
                end = perf_counter()
                total_time = end - start
                print(total_time)
                writefile.close()
     except Exception:
         with open("output.txt", 'a') as writefile1:
             error = """VALUE ERROR on Excel input items! OR Device is 
                     unreachable!\nPlease check/verify the following:
                     \t -On Device, Test if DEVICE is reachable
                     \t -On Excel, Check if "SHOW_OR_CHANGE" ITEMS has value
                     \t -On Excel, Check if other VALUES on COLUMN has values?"""
             print(error)
             writefile1.write(error)
             writefile1.close()

With the "test1.v_hostname_ip" as test1.code argument, If let us say i have 4 network devices 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3, 1.1.1.4, 1.1.1.5 and 1.1.1.3 is unreachable, it goes to the EXCEPTION right away and no longer continue with 1.1.1.4 etc.
How can i be able to still write the exception message to the "output.txt" while still continuing with the program if one of the devices on the list is unreachable or has timed out?
